# How spark jobs are created?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Could someone please let me know how spark jobs are being created. I have a framework which ingests the data to Hive table. However, when I am checking spark UI it's showing that 50,000 job has been created with each stage not processing more than few bytes of data.

Would this create performance issue ?
How to find out why these many jobs are being created?
is it possible to restrict jobs?

[image]

**Code**
Showing code is very difficult for me. It's more than 2000 lines of spark framework. And making MVP is also difficult. However, this is the process.

**I am doing following process for 10k tables.**

1. Read a file (not using spark)
2. Parse a file (not using spark)
3. create dataframe from read data.
4. Figure out deletes and write it to s3
5. Figure out inserts and write it to s3.

Comment: show some of the code pls.

Comment: @thebluephantom showing code is not much possible. I know it's really difficult to understand what's happening without code.